# plotly feature with ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I am plotting all latitude longitude values which I receive on a map like this.

[image]

The map has the color as per the time duration of halt recorded at that point.

My agonies are the following:

- I cannot zoom in and zoom out - Centering the map is very painful - And I have 10*100 such collections to be plotted and evaluated
- I can hardly make out the areas where the halt was specific, all I can see is that it was good with no halt but reality is not that

Hence I looked for plotly and to my surprise they don't have the support.

How can I achieve the results? I don't have a tool like tableau

Please suggest if you can help.

Below code is an example of what I am trying to do with ggmap :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)


lat <- seq(31.26415,31.26831,0.00010)
lon <- seq(76.80890,76.82320,0.00015)
lon <- lon[seq(1,96.2)]
lon <- lon[1:42]
lat_long <- data.frame(lat,lon)

lat_median <- 31.26751
lon_median <- 76.82003

#map <- get_map(location = c(lon_median, lat_median), maptype = "roadmap", zoom = 15)
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon_median, lat_median), zoom = 12, maptype = "roadmap",size = c(600, 300), scale = 2)

ggmap(map) + 
  geom_path(data = lat_long, aes(), size = 2, lineend = "butt") + 
  geom_point(data = lat_long, color = "red3", size = 1)
```

Comment: have you looked into leaflet?

Comment: @MLavoie, will leaflet resolve my issue of zooming in and out of the google map?

Comment: leaflet will create an html map, so zooming in and out will work. you can add points/lines on the maps.